# Can iOS App with single Webpage screen can be uploaded to App Store (**Note:my app contains only one screen** )

Tags: ios, app-store

I need an app to  uploaded to App Store with webPage from URL(**Note:my app contains only one screen** ).Does apple allow to post my app to App Store.

Comment: It is highly probable it will be rejected for being too simple and for being a web page.

Comment: If it's just a web page why do you need an app?

Comment: if you provide the brief information on about your app, apple surely approve , if you have a doubt one of my recent app has relesed the app name is kitLocator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual the answer is "it depends". Your apps has to have a reasonable functionality. Citing the [official review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality):

> 2.12
>
> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
> be rejected